# Using sql string as sql statement in odbc power query in excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am looking to use a string that takes in some parameters from my cells and use it as my sql statement like so:

```
" select * from table where " & data_from_cells & " group by ...;"
```

store it as sqlstring

```
let
mystring = sqlstring,
myQuery = Odbc.Query("driver={Oracle in etc etc etc", mystring)
```

and I run into this error

```
Formula.Firewall: Query '...' (step 'myQuery') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.
```

now apparently I can't combine external queries and another query -- but I am only using passed-on parameters from Excel for my sql string? I am hoping to use `WITH` keyword as well to make nested queries using parameters but it doesn't even let me combine values from excel with an sql statement..

to be clear, the `data_from_cells` was transformed and formatted as a string.

Answer (score 0):

When queries that do stuff are called by other queries that do other stuff, sometimes you can get firewall issues.

The way to get around that is for everything to be done in a single query.

The way to get around *that* without ending up with horrible code is to change your called queries *from* returning the result *to* **functions** that return the result.

For sqlstring:

```
() => " select * from table where " & data_from_cells & " group by ...;" // returns a function that gets the query string when called
```

Then your "myQuery" query can be

```
let
mystring = sqlstring(), //note the parentheses!
myQuery = Odbc.Query("driver={Oracle in etc etc etc", mystring)
```